# Angular 8 delete method is not calling spring boot delete method

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, rest, http

My angular 8 delete method is not calling spring boot delete method (nothing prints in log)

angular 8 delete method :

```
deleteStudent(id: number): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`${this.baseUrl}/deleteById/${id}`);
    return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/deleteById/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });    
  }
```

spring boot delete method (REST API) :

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteById/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?> deleteById(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        try{
            studentService.deleteById(id);
            LOGGER.info("record successfully deleted");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e){

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

after printing the angular url eg: *http://localhost:8888/deleteById/55*  in console I copied it and used in postman, the particular record deleted successfully. This problem only occurs for delete method, another methods are perfectly work.

Comment: did you check your browser network tab for XHR Request/Response. What is the Response Status ?

Comment: Nothing happens in there after pressing delete button ,why is that

Comment: For other methods it's 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake I haven't subscribe to the delete method in service class.